# multiple random images in let it snow plug-in

Tags: javascript, image, random

i've been playing with jason brown's let it snow plug-in.
his code only accommodates for a single custom image, and i've been trying to figure out how to change the code so it accommodates multiple custom images within a random range.

```
!function($){  
var defaults = {
speed: 0,
interaction: true,
size: 2,
count: 200,
opacity: 0,
color: "#ffffff",
windPower: 0,
image: false
};
  $.fn.let_it_snow = function(options){
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options),
    el = $(this),
    flakes = [],
    canvas = el.get(0),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    flakeCount = settings.count,
    mX = -100,
    mY = -100;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

function snow() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
        var flake = flakes[i],
            x = mX,
            y = mY,
            minDist = 100,
            x2 = flake.x,
            y2 = flake.y;

        var dist = Math.sqrt((x2 - x) * (x2 - x) + (y2 - y) * (y2 - y)),
            dx = x2 - x,
            dy = y2 - y;

        if (dist < minDist) {
            var force = minDist / (dist * dist),
                xcomp = (x - x2) / dist,
                ycomp = (y - y2) / dist,
                deltaV = force / 2;

            flake.velX -= deltaV * xcomp;
            flake.velY -= deltaV * ycomp;

        } else {
            flake.velX *= .98;
            if (flake.velY <= flake.speed) {
                flake.velY = flake.speed
            }

            switch (settings.windPower) { 
              case false:
                flake.velX += Math.cos(flake.step += .05) * flake.stepSize;
              break;

              case 0:
                flake.velX += Math.cos(flake.step += .05) * flake.stepSize;
              break;

              default: 
                flake.velX += 0.01 + (settings.windPower/100);
            }
        }

        var s = settings.color;
        var patt = /^#([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})$/;
        var matches = patt.exec(s);
        var rgb = parseInt(matches[1], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[2], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[3], 16);


        flake.y += flake.velY;
        flake.x += flake.velX;

        if (flake.y >= canvas.height || flake.y <= 0) {
            reset(flake);
        }


        if (flake.x >= canvas.width || flake.x <= 0) {
            reset(flake);
        }
        if (settings.image == false) {
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + rgb + "," + flake.opacity + ")"
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
          ctx.fill();
        } else {

          ctx.drawImage($("img#lis_flake").get(0), flake.x, flake.y, flake.size * 2, flake.size * 2);
        }

    }
    requestAnimationFrame(snow);
};


function reset(flake) {

    if (settings.windPower == false || settings.windPower == 0) {
      flake.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
      flake.y = 0;
    } else {
      if (settings.windPower > 0) {
        var xarray = Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width), 0);
        var yarray = Array(0, Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height))
        var allarray = Array(xarray, yarray)

        var selected_array = allarray[Math.floor(Math.random()*allarray.length)];

         flake.x = selected_array[0];
         flake.y = selected_array[1];
      } else {
        var xarray = Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),0);
        var yarray = Array(canvas.width, Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height))
        var allarray = Array(xarray, yarray)

        var selected_array = allarray[Math.floor(Math.random()*allarray.length)];

         flake.x = selected_array[0];
         flake.y = selected_array[1];
      }
    }

    flake.size = (Math.random() * 3) + settings.size;
    flake.speed = (Math.random() * 1) + settings.speed;
    flake.velY = flake.speed;
    flake.velX = 0;
    flake.opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + settings.opacity;
}
 function init() {
  for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
          y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height),
          size = (Math.random() * 3)  + settings.size,
          speed = (Math.random() * 1) + settings.speed,
          opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + settings.opacity;

      flakes.push({
          speed: speed,
          velY: speed,
          velX: 0,
          x: x,
          y: y,
          size: size,
          stepSize: (Math.random()) / 30,
          step: 0,
          angle: 180,
          opacity: opacity
      });
  }

  snow();
}

if (settings.image != false) {
  $("<img src='"+settings.image+"' style='display: none' id='lis_flake'>").prependTo("body")
}

init();

$(window).resize(function() {
  if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
  this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
    el2 = el.clone();
    el2.insertAfter(el);
    el.remove();

    el2.let_it_snow(settings);
  }, 200);
});

if (settings.interaction == true) {
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
      mX = e.clientX,
      mY = e.clientY
  });
}}}(window.jQuery);
```

right at the top of the code, in the defaults properties, is where you point the url of the image. below is what i've put in, so it chooses between image1.jpeg and image2.jpeg

```
image: "img/image'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1)+'.jpeg";
```

however, when the "snowflakes" respawn, the image stays the same instead of choosing a random number again. what do i have to change so that when a snowflake is created, it chooses a random image and becomes it?

i hope my questions is clear, let me know if you need more clarity. i'm new to j-script, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin author loads a single custom image into a hidden element with

```
if (settings.image != false) {
  $("<img src='"+settings.image+"' style='display: none' id='lis_flake'>").prependTo("body")
}
```

and loads the snowflakes with this

```
ctx.drawImage($("img#lis_flake").get(0)
```

---

This solution hasn't been tested, but if you are willing to hack the plugin a bit, you could potentially make the following changes to use two optional images:

**1)** Add this just before the `init();` function call. It adds another hidden image from `settings.image2`.

```
if (settings.image2) {
  $("<img src='"+settings.image2+"' style='display: none' id='lis_flake2'>").prependTo("body")
}
```

**2)** Modify the `function init()` with

```
flakes.push({
    // Create a new property called 'imgNum' to hold either "" or "2";
    imgNum: (settings.image2 && Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0 ? "2" : ""),

    // rest of the code ...
    speed: speed,
```

**3)** Change

```
ctx.drawImage($("img#lis_flake").get(0), flake.x, flake.y, flake.size * 2, flake.size * 2);
```

to

```
ctx.drawImage($("img#lis_flake" + flake.imgNum).get(0), flake.x, flake.y, flake.size * 2, flake.size * 2);
```

to chose the image based on the `flake.imgNum` set randomly in `init()`.

**4)** Change the options you pass into the plugin like so:

```
options = {
    // other options
    image:  "img/image1.jpeg",
    image2: "img/image2.jpeg",
    // other options
}
```

These changes should allow the plugin to still work if `image2` isn't set.